# fetching array column in vuejs

Tags: arrays, function, vue.js

I'm using vuejs in frontend of a laravel project and i want to extract the value from an array column to a new array. Is there a function in vuejs like php's array_column to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const test_arr = [
  { name: 'john', age: 20 },
  { name: 'vali', age: 30 }
]

const array_column = (array = [], column_name = '') => array.map((item, index) => item[column_name])

const another_arr = array_column(test_arr, 'name')
console.log(another_arr)
```